# Blender Python select an object with the sequence of letters in a name

Tags: python, selection-tools

How can I select the object using a sequence of letters in the name . I know there are operators endswith and starswith, they allocate objects to spell the end or the beginning . But how can I select an object if at the beginning and at the end of the characters are the same, but differ only in the middle of the name.
For example, the operator selects the object name in the end:

```
for ob in bpy.context.visible_objects:
      if ob.type == 'MESH' and ob.name.endswith("_P678GHNV"):
          obs.add(ob)
          ob.select = True
```

for example, my naming:

```
_Н480_2_ТХ_VALVE1_Linde_Clea
_Н480_3_ТХ_VALVE2_Linde_Clea
```

And I need to select the objects that include the VALVE in the name

Comment: please show a couple of examples of your naming convention.

Comment: but in this case exactly

Comment: I think whatever way you look at this, it is more a general Python string processing question rather than directly Blender Python related. There will be numerous ways to do it, depending on your object naming convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto) which allow you flexible pattern matching:

```
import re
import bpy

pattern = re.compile("PREFIX.*POSTFIX") # edit this string

for ob in bpy.context.visible_objects:
    if ob.type != 'MESH':
        continue

    match = pattern.match(ob.name)
    if match == None:
        print("no match for %s"  % ob.name)
    else:
        print("matched %s" % match.group())
        ob.select = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's not overlook that you can test if a name contains a certain sequence of letters.

```
for ob in bpy.context.visible_objects:
      if ob.type == 'MESH' and ('VALVE' in ob.name):
          obs.add(ob)
          ob.select = True
```

Comment: for example, my naming: _Н480_2_ТХ_VALVE1_Linde_Clea, _Н480_3_ТХ_VALVE2_Linde_Clea 
And I need to select the objects that include the VALVE in the name