# Change active selection from one object to another, with Python

Tags: python, scripting

I'm making a script to automate some steps I do quite often. In the script I need to change the active selection from one object to another to work on that object and then return the active selection to the first one, e.g. I have a cube and a circle, both separated objects, I do some things with the cube and then I have to select the circle to do some other operations, then when I'm done with that, I want to select the cube to keep working with it, thanks in advance.

Comment: see if this helps https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44382/blender-python-select-an-object-with-the-sequence-of-letters-in-a-name

Comment: That helps to select it, but I want to change the "active" property, so when you go bpy.context.active_object the object is now the second one. In other words I need to convert a secondary selection into the active and the active into the secondary, thanks for the reply nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://caretdashcaret.com/2014/09/30/how-to-select-an-object-in-blender-using-the-api/).

The way you make an object active is through the overwrite of:

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active
```

so if you have a Cube named 'Cube', and you want to make it active, you will do:

```
cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = cube
```